# Libgdx. Rectangle position on screen different from code

Tags: android, libgdx

I’m trying to develop a very simple game for Android using libgdx: there is a bug that appears randomly on the screen and you have to touch it where the bug is to kill it. If you do, the game goes on until you miss three times, and then is game over. Simple enough.

So, I see the bug, I touch it right in the middle, but I miss: the touch point isn’t included in the bug rectangle, which is different from what I see on the screen. I print out the coordinates of both rectangle and point and I see that those of the rectangle were correct a couple of deltaTimes ago, but are no longer, despite of what I see on the screen. I have looked all over the place for a solution, read tutorials, libgdx documentation, but I don’t get it, I'm getting nuts.

This is the code for the touchDown event on the constructor

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            unidadTiempo = unidadTiempo - aceleracion;
            toque.set(screenX, screenY, 0f);
            camara.unproject(toque);

            if (bicho.contains(toque.x, toque.y)) {
                aplastamiento.play();
                bichosLiquidados++;
            } else {
                burla.play();
                vidas--;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the method drawing the bugs and accelerating the bug appearing pace

```
void apareceBicho(){
    ultimoBicho = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    juego.letra.draw(juego.batch, "Puntuacion: " + bichosLiquidados, 0, altoPantalla);
    bicho.setX(xAleatorio);
    bicho.setY(yAleatorio);
    juego.batch.draw(bichoImagen, bicho.x, bicho.y);

    while (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - ultimoBicho < unidadTiempo && vidas > 0){
        unidadTiempo = unidadTiempo - aceleracion;
        xAleatorio = MathUtils.random(randomx);
        yAleatorio = MathUtils.random(randomy);
    }
    if(vidas == 0){

        risa.play();
        TextureRegion fotogramActual = animacionFinal.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        juego.batch.draw(fotogramActual, bicho.x, bicho.y);
        juego.batch.flush();
        gameover = true;
    }
    if (gameover){
        juego.setScreen(new PantallaFinal(juego, this));
    }
}
```

And lastly, the render method

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0.2f, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    camara.update();
    juego.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camara.combined);
    juego.batch.begin();

    juego.batch.draw(yerbita, 0, 0, anchoPantalla, altoPantalla);

    apareceBicho();

    juego.batch.end();
}
```

This is what I meant by a couple of deltaTimes ago:

06-04 09:30:05.942 **RECTANGLE POSITION AIMED TO**: Posicion del bicho: 612.88776, 200.9191, 133.0, 126.0

06-04 09:30:07.950 ACTUAL RECTANGLE POSITION: Posicion del bicho: 426.92572, 111.10537, 133.0, 126.0

06-04 09:30:09.946 **TOUCH POSITION**: Coordenadas toque = 659.2, 250.3111

Comment: show your code, how you create `bicho` ? and `bichoImagen` too ?

Comment: `bichoImagen` is a Texture, nothing strange there. `bicho` is the Rectangle I have issues with. It is created in the constructor. Afterwards, its x and y properties are given randomly.

Comment: Ya I need that code, that is useful in finding your bug ?, edit question and add code of constructor .

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason :

`bicho` having zero width and height.

If you created rectangle by default constructor then need to be set width and hight of that rectangle.

```
bicho = new Rectangle();
bicho.setSize(bichoImagen.getWidth(),bichoImagen.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek, but both width and height were given to the rectangle in the constructor. I think the problem has to do something with deltaTime or double buffering

Comment: why don't you try `Sprite` instead of `texture+rectangle` , Sprite having `bounds` a `Rectangle` as  data member.